# Why doesn't Haskell's Data.Set support infinite sets?

Tags: haskell, set

In the following snippet:

```
import qualified Data.Set as Set

data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat deriving (Eq, Show, Ord)

instance Enum Nat where
  pred (Succ x)     = x
  succ x            = Succ x
  toEnum 0          = Zero
  toEnum x          = Succ (toEnum (x-1))
  fromEnum Zero     = 0
  fromEnum (Succ x) = 1 + (fromEnum x)

nats :: [Nat]
nats = [Zero ..]

natSet :: Set.Set Nat
natSet = Set.fromList nats
```

Why does:

- `elem (toEnum 100) nats` == `True`

but

- `Set.member (toEnum 100) natSet` never ends?

Answer (score 15):

The existing answers are sufficient, but I want to expound a little bit on the behavior of `Set`s.

Looks like you are hoping for a lazy set of all `Nat`s; you take the infinite list of all `Nat`s and use `Set.toList` on it. That would be nice; mathematicians often talk in terms of the "set of all natural numbers". The problem is the implementation of `Set` is not as accommodating of laziness as lists are.

> The implementation of Set is based on size balanced binary trees (or
>   trees of bounded balance)
>
> *[The docs for Data.Set](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/latest/doc/html/Data-Set.html#t:Set)*

Suppose you wish to lazily construct a binary tree from a list. Elements from the list would only be inserted into the tree when a deeper traversal of the tree was necessary. So then you ask if 100 is in the tree. It would go along adding numbers 1-99 to the tree, one at a time. Then it would finally add 100 to the tree, and discover that 100 is indeed an element in the tree. But notice what we did. We just performed an in-order traversal of the lazy list! So the first time, our imaginary `LazyTree.contains` would have roughly the same complexity as `List.find` (assuming an ammortized *O(1)* insert, which is a bad assumption for a simple binary tree, which would have *O(log n)* complexity). And without balancing, our tree would be very lopsided (we added the numbers 1 through 100 in order, so it would just be a big linked list down the right child of each branch). But with tree balancing *during the traversal*, it would be hard to know where to begin the traversal again; at least it certainly wouldn't be immediately intuitive.

tl;dr: nobody (afaik) has made a good lazy Set yet. So infinite Sets are more easily represented as infinite lists, for now.

Comment: Even more general is representing infinite sets by functions :-)

Comment: In this case you might say the `toEnum` function represents the infinite set of `Nat`s, then...each element indexed by...the element itself in Integer form?

Answer (score 8):

`Set.fromList` is not lazy, so it will not end if you pass it an infinite list. But `natSet` is not constructed until it is needed, so you only notice it when you run `Set.member` on it.

For example, even `Set.null $ Set.fromList [0..]` does not terminate.

Comment: You can see in the [source of Set.fromList](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/latest/doc/html/src/Data-Set.html#fromList) it is implemented with `foldlStrict`. (Why it doesn't use `foldl'` I'm not certain but it's apparently the same.)

Answer (score 4):

You can't have infinite sets. This doesn't just affect `Set.member`, whenever you do anything which will cause `natSet` to be evaluated even one step (even `Set.null`), it will go into an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see what happens when we adapt [GHC's Set code](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/latest/doc/html/src/Data-Set.html) to accommodate infinite sets:

```
module InfSet where

data InfSet a = Bin a (InfSet a) (InfSet a) 

-- create an infinite set by unfolding a value
ofUnfold :: (x -> (x, a, x)) -> x -> InfSet a
ofUnfold f x = 
  let (lx,a,rx) = f x
      l = ofUnfold f lx
      r = ofUnfold f rx
  in Bin a l r

-- check for membership in the infinite set
member :: Ord a => a -> InfSet a -> Bool
member x (Bin y l r) = case compare x y of
                         LT -> member x l
                         GT -> member x r
                         EQ -> True       

-- construct an infinite set representing a range of numbers
range :: Fractional a => (a, a) -> InfSet a
range = ofUnfold $ \(lo,hi) -> 
          let mid = (hi+lo) / 2
          in ( (lo, mid), mid, (mid, hi) )
```

Note how, instead of constructing the infinite set from an infinite list,
I instead define a function `ofUnfold` to unfold a single value into an infinite list.
It allows us to construct both branches lazily in parallel (we don't need to finish
one branch before constructing another).

Let's give it a whirl:

```
ghci> :l InfSet
[1 of 1] Compiling InfSet           ( InfSet.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: InfSet.
ghci> let r = range (0,128)
ghci> member 64 r
True
ghci> member 63 r
True
ghci> member 62 r
True
ghci> member (1/2) r
True
ghci> member (3/4) r
True
```

Well, that seems to work.  What if we try a value outside of the Set?

```
ghci> member 129 r
^CInterrupted.
```

That will just run and run and never quit.  There's no stopping branches in the inifinite set,
so the search never quits.  We could check the original range somehow, but that's not practical for infinite sets of discrete elements:

```
ghci> let ex = ofUnfold (\f -> ( f . (LT:), f [EQ], f . (GT:) )) id
ghci> :t ex
ex :: InfSet [Ordering]
ghci> member [EQ] ex
True
ghci> member [LT,EQ] ex
True
ghci> member [EQ,LT] ex
^CInterrupted.
```

So infinite sets are *possible* but I'm not sure they're *useful*.

Comment: `range` will return an infinite set only in the case of floating point numbers. It isn't infinite if instead integers are used, am I wrong?

Comment: @is7s: Well, there's only a finite number of floating point numbers, so actually `range (0, 1) :: InfSet Float` has finite distinct elements.  But, since `range` used `ofUnfold`, the generated data structure will be infinite in size (consider `range (0,0)`).

Answer (score 0):

I felt the same way so I added a set that works with infinite Lists. However they need to be sorted, so my algorithm knowns when to stop looking for more.

```
Prelude> import Data.Set.Lazy
Prelude Data.Set.Lazy> natset = fromList [1..]
Prelude Data.Set.Lazy> 100 `member` natset
True
Prelude Data.Set.Lazy> (-10) `member` natset
False
```

Its on hackage. 
http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lazyset-0.1.0.0/docs/Data-Set-Lazy.html