# Infinite Maps in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I was writing some code and I figured that I'd be able to create an infinite map from an infinite list of tuples. Something along the lines of the following:
`Map.fromList [(i,i+1)|i<-[1..]]`

Of course, I discovered immediately that Data.Map and Data.Set do not support infinite Maps and Sets respectively. I noticed a similar question about Data.Set's greedy implementation of `fromList`, and, after reading over the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7123501/why-doesnt-haskells-data-set-support-infinite-sets), it's clear that both lazy and greedy implementations are possible for Set, just that the greedy ones work better. I don't really understand, however, why a lazy implementation of `Map.fromList` wouldn't work. Something to do with how keys are stored?

Comment: How would you know which element of the list would be the root node of the final tree without knowing the whole list?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`Data.Map` is implemented as a balanced tree (roughly binary, I think); it's hard to create and balance infinite binary trees lazily without some foreknowledge about the input! However, you might like something like the [MemoTrie](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MemoTrie) package, which uses lazy infinite tries (of bits) instead.

```
> let x = trie (\x -> x+1)
> untrie x 72
73
> untrie x 37
38
```